# HHVM 3.7.0 Postgresql PDO

Tags: postgresql, pdo, installation, hhvm, centos7

I do realize that HHVM does not support Postgres, but there are extensions for hiphop which allow use of the postgres PDO.

I have successfully compiled hhvm and installed hhvm with the following commands

```
[root@localhost ~]# git clone https://github.com/facebook/hhvm -b master  hhvm  --recursive
[root@localhost ~]# cd hhvm
[root@localhost hhvm]# ./configure
[root@localhost hhvm]# make -j5
[root@localhost hhvm]# make install
```

That has worked fine, and i have since developed the need to connect to a postgres database.

**Attempt 1**

The following page suggests to add `--with-pdo-pgsql=/path/to/pg_config` argument when configuring.
http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php

```
[root@localhost hhvm]# find / -name pg_config
/usr/bin/pg_config
[root@localhost hhvm]# ./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_config
[root@localhost hhvm]# make -j5
[root@localhost hhvm]# make install
```

and did not see any improvement

```
[root@localhost hhvm]# hhvm ~/test.php
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /root/test.php on line 2
```

**Attempt 2**

The hhvm wiki extensions page (https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions) links to https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql

I followed the steps to make the hhvm-pgsql extension.

```
[root@localhost ~]# git clone https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql.git
[root@localhost ~]# cd hhvm-pgsql
[root@localhost hhvm-pgsql]# hphpize
[root@localhost hhvm-pgsql]# cmake .
[root@localhost hhvm-pgsql]# make
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pgsql.dir/pgsql.cpp.o
In file included from /root/hhvm-pgsql/pgsql.cpp:2:0:
/root/hhvm-pgsql/pgsql.h:6:45: fatal error: hphp/runtime/base/base-includes.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hphp/runtime/base/base-includes.h"
                                             ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pgsql.dir/pgsql.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pgsql.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Obviously i am missing base-includes.h. I am unsure where to get it from. Im assuming its in the hhvm-dev package the repo mentions, but where should i get the necessary files seeing as though i just compiled hhvm?

```
[root@localhost hhvm]# find / -name base-includes.h
```

finds nothing.

**Extra information**

```
[root@localhost hhvm]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
[root@localhost hhvm]# hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.7.0-dev (rel)
Compiler: heads/master-0-g6bec157aad74985e64d3d9fe928ad5cc490f5876
Repo schema: e36ae4255d99eb78d62256c73ee53fadb05d65e0
```

I have also followed the steps on https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-Packages-on-Centos-7.x to install it all via yum. I have found that works, but that hhvm version has some bugs which have since been fixed.
As i was writing this, i tried pulling the `pgsql.so` installed from `yum install hhvm-ext-pgsql` which resulted in the error below. (understandably).

```
[root@localhost ~]# hhvm test.php
Uncaught exception: Could not load extension /usr/local/lib64/hhvm/extensions/pgsql.so: getModuleBuildInfo() symbol not defined. (/usr/local/lib64/hhvm/extensions/pgsql.so: undefined symbol: getModuleBuildInfo)
Core dumped: Segmentation fault
Stack trace in /tmp/stacktrace.4181.log
Segmentation fault
```

**Anyways, my question is...**

What am i doing wrong/missing in Attempt 1?

How can i successfully complete Attempt 2?

- Is it assumed knowledge?
- How can i sovle this in the future without asking a question here, keeping in mind i have attempted the usual research and google and found nothing of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 1 is just not going to work, the docs are simply wrong, and [I filed an issue about it](https://github.com/hhvm/hack-hhvm-docs/issues/530).

Attempt 2, the PocketRent extension, is the right direction, though the extension might not have been updated recently. You should report the compilation failure [on their issue tracker](https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql/issues) (or search the tracker for an existing issue, though none jumps out at me). The guys who built it are quite good, though they sometimes forget to update the extension when HHVM changes, until someone reminds them :)

I would not use the prebuilt extension here; extensions need to be built against exactly the version of HHVM they are running against. The crash you're seeing is, I suspect, due to mixing an extension built with one version of HHVM with running it on another. (This should produce a useful error, but we had a bug recently where we wouldn't detect this and would crash instead!)

Comment: Thanks for filing the issue, Ill look into what you said about attempt 2, and mark as the answer after i speak to them. Regarding the prebuilt one, i only mentioned it in the question so it wouldn't be suggested by others. I didn't think it would work anyway. The stack trace did produce what looks to be useful information anyways.